# How can I add new words or vocabulary into kaldi platform?

Tags: speech-recognition, models, voice-recognition, toolkit

I am trying to create a `ASR system` with existing pre-trained models available as a sample. I got stuck in a place where how to add new words into that trained model, so that next time it will correctly return the word; Some sort of machine learning concept. Any ideas will be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

There are two things you might need:

1. Lexicon: Try to find something like `lexicon.txt` in your data folder, add your words and corresponding phone sequences in it, like:

   ```
   speech s p iy ch
   the dh ax
   the dh iy
   ```
2. Language Model: Find something like `XXX.lm` in your data folder, add your word in 1-gram with a probabiliy, like:

   ```
   \data\
   ngram 1=200
   ngram 2=4000
   ...

   \1-grams
   -7.3241 the
   ...
   ```

After this, make the decoder `HCLG.fst` again based on these 2 new files.

**Note:** Numbers in language will make the results of speech recognition different, you need to choose a proper number, or use toolkit `srilm` to generate it by the text of your corpus.

Comment: This answer is the right way to go, any idea on how to add unigram to ARPA file? Manually?